# How to use RSA signature to verify AWS instance identity document in C++

Tags: amazon-web-services, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to verify an AWS instance identity document with RSA in C++. (I must precise that I'm not very good in cryptography.)

## With openssl cmd-line utility -> OK

I [started from this AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/verify-rsa2048.html).

As I understand it:

- `rsa2048.txt` contains the base64-encoded RSA Signature (with `-----BEGIN/END PKCS7-----` headers/footers)
- `public_certificate.pem` contains the base64-encoded public certificate (with `-----BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE-----` headers/footers)

All the AWS tutorial this works well i.e. the following command works...

```
openssl smime -verify -in rsa2048.txt -inform PEM -certfile public_certificate.pem -noverify
```

... and returns my instance identity document (= the same content than a HTTP request to `/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document`), along with the message "`Verification successful`" (so as I understand it, it validates and decodes the document).

**Edit** : I discovered that by doing `cat rsa2048.txt |grep -v \- | base64 --decode` I can also retrieve the document (along with the signature in binary data I guess?), so it is not *RSA-encoded*, just base64-encoded.

## With openssl C++ library

Now I want to do the **same** without relying on openssl binary program, and do it inside a C++ binary. (Also ideally I'd like to do it from memory instead of loading files from disk, but that's not even the issue here.)

I tried several approaches, the latest being trying to start from this OpenSSL example program : [openssl-3.0.11/demos/smime/smver.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/demos/smime/smver.c). The test programs works compiles, and works without error if I don't change anything:

```
g++ smsign.c -lssl -lcrypto -o smsign && ./smsign
g++ smver.c -lssl -lcrypto -o smver && ./smver
```

And if I try to modify smver with my own inputs:

- I replace the input file `cacert.pem` by `public_certificate.pem`
- change the input file `smout.txt` this way:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/signed; protocol="application/x-pkcs7-signature"; micalg="sha-256"; boundary="----FFA67CA588746345E0C5B48EFD8EB3C9"

This is an S/MIME signed message

------FFA67CA588746345E0C5B48EFD8EB3C9
Content-type: text/plain

<... my JSON instance identity document here ...>


------FFA67CA588746345E0C5B48EFD8EB3C9
Content-Type: application/x-pkcs7-signature; name="smime.p7s"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"

MIAGC<... the contents of the rsa2048.txt file here (without header/footer)...>==

------FFA67CA588746345E0C5B48EFD8EB3C9--
```

I then get the following error :

```
PKCS7_get0_signers:signer certificate not found:crypto/pkcs7/pk7_smime.c:430:
```

I also tried with different flags for `PKCS7_verify` (like `PKCS7_NOVERIFY`), but it does not work either.

I also tried with [openssl-3.0.11/demos/smime/smdec.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/demos/smime/smdec.c) , but the input file `signer.pem` must contain both the certificate and **the RSA private key** ... which I don't have? (Isn't that the whole idea of a public-key cryptosystem, that Amazon keeps the RSA private key and only gives me the public one?) **Edit** : I guess it makes sense because my goal is not actually decoding a message (which I cannot do), but validating / checking the signature ; so this example program is not for me.